# Making form button label/text responsive

Tags: css, button

I am currently building a form using div tag however, I am having issues with the button and it's text. On desktop website the form looks fine, however, whenever on mobile device, the submit and reset button text staying ( centered aligned) but the text isn't behaving as it should be.

Please can someone help me on this?[image]

[Link to the site.](http://a2zhouse.co.uk/anam-testing/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the following style to the div that wrap those buttons.

```
display:flex; 
flex-wrap:wrap; 
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

On your site there is a certain CSS rule that makes your buttons take up to 25% width of their parent:

```
.submit, .reset {
  max-width: 25%;
  ...
}
```

To make these buttons take let's say 100% when browser's width is below 600px write:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .submit, .reset {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Of course it has to go below `max-width: 25%` rule so it does't get overridden.

Comment: Just added your code, it works fine, however, there is too much gap between submit and reset button after the collapse.

Comment: @TicketForLessUK There is no gap as far as I can see so how can there be too big gap?

Answer (score 0):

This happening because that button's size is determined by font width + padding around it when there's enough room. Whenever the room provided by surrounding div, is not enough (ex. on smaller screen) it no longer relies on font width and tries to maintain the button size with it's padding. So first things first, that is actually an expected behavior.

What could you do to resolve this depends on what kind of solution do you wanna end up with, a quick solution is:

1- You might either go for @media queries or bootstrap maybe, and let buttons go full size of screen (taking full line, like a row)

You wouldn't like to have those two buttons at one line on mobile anyway, Say you did it and with a script making text smaller? then how could user read it at the end? This is not a good idea.

Comment: His site makes them 98% width but there is other rule `max-width: 25%` so that's his problem. Those particular buttons' width isn't calculated by text. What he has on this website is bad design if you ask.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `max-width: 25%;` on the buttons.

You can use something like this on the buttons:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
max-width: 220px;
```

You may want to use media queries :

```
@media(max-width: 480px) {
    .yourClass{

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a maximum width set on the submit and reset classes:

```
 .submit, .reset {
     max-width: 25%;
```

When the container gets smaller, the buttons will refuse to get any wider (and stack I assume). You can set a max-width of 100% at the smaller breakpoints or an explicit width:

```
 @media (max-width: 600px) {
      .submit, .reset {
         max-width: 100%;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your orginal code you have:

```
.submit, .reset {
    max-width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: orange !important;
    z-index: 8;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-family: Montserrat;
    background-color: rgb(247, 153, 31);
    border-radius: 30px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    visibility: inherit;
    transition: none;
    text-align: inherit;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 17px 32px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

From the above code, I removed `padding: 17px 32px;`. This was then replaced with `height: 40px !important;`. The paddings were causing the buttons to become unresponsive on mobile browsing. Setting the height solves the problem !

[image]

Comment: Leon I removed Linek's code and tested yours. Works fine however, I am still missing the last part of submit and reset.